# Move data from a postgres database to another database with a different owner

Tags: postgresql

I have two postgres databases with the same structure and tables, hosted on the same server, the databases are owned by different users:

**database1**: **owner1**

**database2**: **owner2**

I want to know the best way to copy the content of **database1** into **database2** (overriding the original content of **database2**).

I tried **pg_dump** & **pg_restore** but the dump will explicitly specify **owner1** as the owner of the tables and then I have permission issues when trying to get the data from **database2** using **owner2**. I had to manually re-grant all privileges on **database2** to **owner2** and set the owner of all tables again to **owner2**.

My approach:

```
pg_dump database1 > database1.psql
```

```
postgres=# drop database database2;
postgres=# create database database2;
```

```
psql --d database2  -f database1.psql
```

Is there a simpler way to copy the data from **database1** to **database2** without having to update the user permissions manually after the restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) to specify that you don't want to export ownership:

- `-O` (or `--no-owner`) does not export ownership
- `-x` (or `--no-privileges`) Prevent dumping of access privileges (grant/revoke commands)

```
    pg_dump db_name -O -x > output_file
```

Comment: Thank you, but should I then re-specify the owner when restoring the database?